# how to run mysql command with nohup

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, scripting

could someone assist me to run this query with nohup, how should I do?
with the below command, I faced an error

```
nohup mysql -u -p -A tablename " select distinct t2.white, t1.red from table t1 inner join temp t2 on t1.Data=t2.white INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';" &
```

Comment: Any reason for not sharing the exact error message with us?

Comment: error message like this:nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Answer (score 0):

please try

```sh
nohup mysql -u -p -A tablename " select distinct t2.white, t1.red from table t1 inner join temp t2 on t1.Data=t2.white INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';" 2>&1 &
```

Comment: It doesn't work. :( same error and exit after running this command

Comment: mysql -u -p -A databasename.    not tablename

Comment: 'mysql -u -p -A databasename -e " select distinct t2.IM, t1.MS from Req t1 inner join temp t2 on t1.Data=t2.IM;" &>> /tmp/MS.csv & disown'

Comment: I tried this but again it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When no redirection output is added after the nohup command, "nohup: ignoring inpu... " will be printed by default and then exit. The actual command is already running in the background.

You can use to increase the redirection command, nohup will not output the ignorein error.

```
nohup xxx> /tmp/nohup.log &
```

You should check if your sql file is generated;